# How to fetch full URL path "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/2#document" in PHP or Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, url-parameters

I want to fetch full URL path "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/2#document" using PHP or Laravel framework. I have tried to fetch using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but it did not work.

Comment: Take a look at [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: The browser doesn't send the url fragment to the server.

Comment: Where do you want to take it out?
controller? blade?

Comment: You can't get the `#document` to come to the server though as URL fragments aren't sent to the server. If `#document` is so necessary, encode the fragment in a get parameter and send it.

Answer (score -1):

If I got your question right, you want to get the current URL of a page you are on? If that's the case, there's a `url()` helper method which outputs the current URL you're on. Inside your controller, do this:

```
$url = Request::url(); 
echo $url;
```

EDIT:

If you have some queries present in your logic, you can use `getRequestUri()` method:

```
$url = Request::getRequestUri(); 
echo $url;
```

You can read more in official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests).

Comment: I have tried but perfect URL not fetched. I want to fetch value after # tag. for ex. "#document".